# Python string splitting

Tags: python, string, hex

I need to take a hex pair, such as `7A` and break it into `7` and `A` as separate variables for further manipulation. What would be the proper method to go about splitting this string, as I'm not trying to remove any characters, and I don't have any delimiters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To split them " as separate variables for further manipulation " :**

```
s = "7A"
firstHex, secondHex = list(s)
```

**Output:**

```
firstHex = 7
secondHex = A
```

NOTE: It will only work if there're two-digit hexadecimal characters.

Comment: This also works, and it removes the surrounding '' on 7 and A.

Comment: This only works as expected if there are only two characters in the hex string. If the hex value is a longer number you get an error.

Comment: @EbiDK Thank you for reminding. I totally forgot to mention that in my answer.

Comment: @herinkc: If I needed to split a string with more than two non-hexadecimal characters, would this method work?

Comment: @user1 It won't work unless you assign the same numbers of variable with the length of your hexadecimal numbers. For example, if you have `4 characters long string`, you also need `4 variables` to hold it. Eg. `one, two, three, four = list("7A4F")`

Comment: So the code: 's = 0110' 'first, second, third, fourth = list(s)' should work?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm):

`list('7A')` which will return a list containing 7 and A:

```
['7', 'A'] #Note that the single quote will not appear when you print the content :)
```

(`list('7A')[0]` contains 7 and `list('7A')[1]` contains A)

Or by:

```
[x for x in '7A']
```

If you have more than 2 chars in your string and you write:

```
lst = list(youtString)
```

Then `lst` will contain all the chars of the string.

Comment: Is is possible to use your method, but remove the surrounding '' on 7 and A?

Comment: When you extract the item from the list, there will be no `'`

Comment: I tested the code as follows: 'a = list('7A')[0]' 'print a' and I get ''7''.